# Passive voice, Present Simple, Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, present-simple

> The washing machine was broken, but it is OK now.

>

> It is repaired.

vs

> It has been repaired.

>

Please explain the correct choice. Is it possible that both are correct here?

Comment: For example, a repairer could say to his employer, that "this washing machine is repaired" or it is not correct grammatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Repaired" really just refers to the process the washing machine underwent, not its present state.

"*The washing machine is under repair*", or "*the washing machine is being repaired*" would describe its state *while the repair was underway*.

Once the repair is over, *the washing machine **has been repaired***.

The machine is now in a working state, so *the washing machine **is working***.

Comment: Am I right, that this choice is appropriate for all mechanisms, because they are damaged all time? But if it is some thing that is needed only 1 time to repair in its life, I should say that it is repaired.

Comment: Technically, no - although sometimes even english speakers say things wrong, or they become idiomatic. "Damage" is something that is inflicted upon something. For example, if you hit your washing machine with a hammer you are *damaging* it. Afterwards, the machine *has been damaged*. The state it is now in is "broken", so *the washing machine is broken*. But, some people might say "it *is* damaged", and people do idiomatically refer to partially broken items for sale as "damaged goods".

Comment: I`m sorry but you said that "repaired" it is only a process, not state. But in Longman dictionary "repair" is to do some work on something that is damaged or not working properly, so that it is in good condition again. So, condition here is a state. May be you could correct your answer?

Comment: I thought that if a washing machine has been repaired, it is repaired only before it`s using. When a person starts to use it again, it may be break down again for example because of any other problem.

Comment: For example, a repairer could say to his employer, that "this washing machine is repaired" or it is not correct?

Comment: @Sergey He might say it, if that is accepted *terminology* in his place of work. From a strict grammatical point of view though, I believe it should be "this washing machine *has been* repaired", or "I repaired this washing macine".

Comment: Thank you for your answers!